# Possible reputation padding?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, accepted-answer, sock-puppets

I just recently answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321341/find-the-number-of-zero-elements-in-a-matrix-in-matlab) on Stack Overflow.  Though there was already an accepted answer, I decided to put my two cents in with an alternative answer for research purposes.

In any case, for my own curiosity, I decided to take a look at the profile of [the person who had their answer accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711075/nematollah-zarmehi), as well as [the person who asked the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3942944/amoadi).  The user who asked the question is a new user who has been around for 2 days so far.  They have also already asked 4 questions, with all accepted answers, which is great.

However, what caught my attention was the following: For each question that the new user asked, the other user who I just referred to seems to immediately answer, with their answer marked as accepted. This has happened for all 4 questions that the new user has asked.  Specifically:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318029/report-the-results-of-matlab-code-on-a-window

   - Question posted: 2014-08-14 - 21:43:05 Zulu
   - Question answered: 2014-08-14 - 21:43:47 Zulu
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320319/extraction-audio-from-video-using-avconv

   - Question posted: 2014-08-15 - 02:11:13 Zulu
   - Question answered: 2014-08-15 - 02:12:26 Zulu
3. [Find the number of zero elements in a matrix in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321341/find-the-number-of-zero-elements-in-a-matrix-in-matlab)

   - Question posted: 2014-08-15 - 04:39:01 Zulu
   - Question answered: 2014-08-15 - 04:39:42 Zulu
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322881/change-the-style-of-page-number-to-persian-in-microsoft-word-2013

   - Question posted: 2014-08-15 - 07:45:25 Zulu
   - Question answered: 2014-08-15 - 07:45:52 Zulu

I extracted the times from the post and the answer by simply hovering over the date above the user's avatar in their respective post / answer.  As @RetoKoradi noticed, though two of the questions are related to one programming paradigm, the other two questions are of completely different topics but follow the same immediate post-accept pattern.

---

Maybe I'm looking too much into this, but I find it very peculiar that there are four questions asked by the same author, and answered by the same user where each answer arrived within less than a minute on average between post and answer.

Could this be a possible sign of reputation padding?  If it isn't, then this is more of a question for my own curiosity.  If there are signs that there are two people working together - one asking questions, and the other one answering those questions in order to buff up the reputation of the one answering the questions, how does this get handled?  Is this allowed or tolerated behaviour?

I hope that I'm not coming across the wrong way!  This is more for curiosity than anything else.

---

## Edit - August 16th, 2014

As per the discussion with myself, Marc Glisse and Franck Dernoncourt, even with the small time difference in between post and answer, if the *quality* of the question and answer is  quite good, then I probably would have not raised this issue in the first place.

As I think about it more, I focused more on the *quality* of the aforementioned questions and answers rather than the time difference.  I suppose I used the time difference as the catalyst for raising this issue, but I was more miffed about the actual questions and answers themselves.

Franck raised a very good point where if there are two (or multiple) people in a Q & A team, and they post questions and answers with issues that they have encountered, then that is quite productive and very useful to disseminate.  Most of the above questions that I referenced provided little to no value and that using a search engine with some very simple key words would have been a more logical step to take rather than posting on Stack Overflow.

Either way, this was something great for me to take in, and also a great way to start getting myself involved here on Meta!

Comment: I could see it happening if they were all under the same or very similar tags, because somebody could be sitting there with their fingers on the keyboard. But with one being about a completely different topic, I agree that it looks kind of odd.

Comment: I would say flag it for moderation attention with a custom flag, giving exactly that information.

Comment: @Sumurai8 - Thanks for your input!  Would I flag all of them?  Also, my description is rather verbose.  Could I simply provide a link to this Meta SO post as the description, and would that be sufficient?

Comment: @RetoKoradi - I agree, and that's the final thing that tipped me off.  One of those questions was on a different topic.

Comment: @rayryeng In this case you found a pattern. A moderator must judge *all the posts at once* based on the pattern you found. Just flag 1 post where you describe this pattern.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - Looks like they've done one more.  I've updated my post with the additional pattern.  I'm going to wait and see what happens after the end of the day, then contact SO if I feel that there's something definitely serious going on.

Comment: "with their answer marked as accepted right after."  I thought new users had a "waiting period" before they could accept an answer?

Comment: @JohnnyBones - You're right.  There is a 15 minute grace period.  I'll edit my post to make this clear... but the post-accept pattern is still there (I think).

Comment: If at least they were good questions and good answers...

Comment: @MarcGlisse - You're right.  I wouldn't have even brought up this issue if they were at least questions and answers that were meaningful.  The fact that they were about very trivial things didn't help.

Comment: I think the quality is the only issue: if members of a team decide to share their Q&A here, it benefits to everybody.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - You're right.  In hindsight, I focused more on the quality of the question and answer rather than the actual time difference between the question and answer. I should probably include this in my post and emphasize this. If the quality of the questions and answers were good, then I wouldn't have a problem with people working together.  That is a very good point that you have brought up.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I looked. They probably work together, but I didn't see:

- Any votes going to things that other, completely disconnected and unrelated users didn't vote the same way on
- A substantial number of votes to begin with, less than 10 to be clear

If you have a concern like this going forward, it's best to [contact  us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) directly to raise it - when it's brought up here it draws an inordinate amount of attention on certain users, which can sometimes have unintended effects. I'm sure there's no harm done this time, as it does look completely benign, and it's not like low-quality stuff is getting votes it wouldn't otherwise receive (which is the main reason why we're strict about targeted votes).

Also, don't forget - the system automatically reverses targeted patterns based on a *reasonably* tight criteria, which didn't trip here (but could, if it continued) - at which point the mods might elect to send a helpful message about it.

For now, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you Tim!  I should have known to just contact SO directly.  The reason why I wanted to bring it up here was because I wanted to see if anyone else saw a pattern, and it turns out I wasn't the only one.  BTW, those two just did it again, and it was for a post that is completely unrelated to programming in general.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322881/change-the-style-of-page-number-to-persian-in-microsoft-word-2013 - I'm going to wait until the end of the day and see how many more these two are going to generate and I'll contact SO if I think there's still a problem.

Comment: Speculation - If someone were to have been question banned, the thing to do is "contribute positively"... Like post answers. To avoid getting a serial vote reversal, just have the person asking accept the answer (and née users can't up vote anyways). It *might* get one out of the question ban.