# What should I do when I see users collaborating to keep a bounty's reputation between them?

Tags: discussion, bounty

So there was this question on SO which wasn't a very good question to begin with. It didn't get any attention because of that and someone, presumably a friend of the OP offered a bounty on it.

I posted an answer on it and it was accepted by the OP. However soon afterwards, the OP himself posted an answer which basically admitted that it is based on mine, adding:

> this does not solve the problem, it only makes it less annoying.

But the bounty was awarded to this answer. So it seems to have been an exercise to preserve the rep. Is this legit? If not, what should I do in these cases?

---

I have seen questions like [How comes this bounty was awarded?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319845/how-comes-this-bounty-was-awarded) and [Possible reputation padding?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268821/possible-reputation-padding) but they do not seem applicable in this case.

It seems somewhat related to [On dealing with the misuse of bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260583/on-dealing-with-the-misuse-of-bounties) but this is a one of case rather than serial bounty abuse.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yeah, there was some sketchy stuff happening there I'm afraid - more than just the apparent use of an answer to get the bounty's promotion while avoiding losing the reputation. You might note that one of those accounts no longer exists...

Mods can usually take care of this; if you suspect there's something untoward happening, flag and they'll investigate. But since you posted here, I've cleaned it up and marked your flag helpful.

#### See also: [What exactly is "artificial inflation of reputation", and where is the line?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318497/what-exactly-is-artificial-inflation-of-reputation-and-where-is-the-line/318499#318499)